# Multiple series tooltip with irregular data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to add two datasets to a `line` chart, but the problem is: I want to enable showing the tooltip for both datasets when (one of two):

1. Hover on a data line (without a data point) and show all `line` chart data
2. Hover on a data point, but sho the data of all the `line` charts

A fiddle I experimented with: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gjbXqb?editors=0010

Comment: Your fiddle is not saved :( Could you update it? Thanks!

Comment: Hope it's fine now (:

Comment: Nope, it's still empty :) URL wrong maybe?

Comment: I hope the third time is the charm (:

Comment: Yup, perfect, thanks! Now, just to clarify, you simply want to display **all** points in the tooltip, no matter what user hover? Sorry, I don't see difference between v1 and v2.

Comment: Yes, I just want to hover on any line (not precisely on a data point), and on the tooltip see all of the chart data.

In general it would be just to show the data on the x-axis from all the line graphs

Comment: Ok, but sometimes your lines don't have values on the x-axis, then that value should be calculated (interpolated)? If yes, then see Highcharts' [UserVoice](https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/5462529-tooltip-data-interpolation) ticket.

Comment: Yes, that's the one! Thank you much!